# How does the -m flag differ betwen Python 2 and 3?

Tags: python, command-line

In Python 3, I could use the -m flag in the command line to run any directory as a Python package, or to run python modules inside those directories with relative imports in them. However, that does not seem to be the case in Python 2.

Let's say I have the following file structure:

```
C:\mflag
└───pack
        hey.py
```

And that the contents of hey.py are:

```
from __future__ import print_function

print("Hello!")
```

Why is the behavior of these two commands different?

```
C:\mflag>python -m pack.hey
Hello!

C:\mflag>python2 -m pack.hey
C:\Python27\python2.exe: No module named pack
```

Comment: Suspect it's probably something to do with [namespace packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/)

Comment: I believe you should have a `pack\__init__.py` to make it an official package. Python 3 may be being a bit more flexible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a namespaced package, introduced by [PEP 0420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/); specifically:

> During import processing, the import machinery will continue to
> iterate over each directory in the parent path as it does in Python
> 3.2. While looking for a module or package named "foo", for each directory in the parent path:
>
> - If /foo/_ _ init _ _.py is found, a regular package is imported
>   and returned.
> - If not, but /foo.{py,pyc,so,pyd} is found, a
>   module is imported and returned. The exact list of extension varies by
>   platform and whether the -O flag is specified. The list here is
>   representative.
> - If not, but /foo is found and is a
>   directory, it is recorded and the scan continues with the next
>   directory in the parent path.
> - Otherwise the scan continues with the next directory in the parent path.

Comment: Excellent answer to OP's explicit "*Why?*" question. It may also be worth noting that OP can have his desired behavior in Python2 by creating an empty `pack\__init__.py`. That would answer his implicit "*How?*" question.

Comment: That was it! Another relevat section from the same PEP:
"Allowing implicit namespace packages means that the requirement to provide an __init__.py file can be dropped completely"